# Get only subdirectories

Tags: dart, directory

How to get only a list of subdirectories within a directory?

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  // Get the system temp directory.
  var systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;

  // List directory contents, not recursing into sub-directories,
  // not following symbolic links.
  await for (var entity in
      systemTempDir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)) {
    print(entity.path);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final dir = Directory.systemTemp;
  final files = dir.listSync();
  // get the subdirectories
  for (final f in files) {
    if (f is Directory) {
      print(f.path);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, didn't know about the -is keyword. Was searching for `.isFile`. Had found a solution with this: `entity.toString().split(":")[0] == "Directory"` but probably a lot more overhead. :)